# Split an list of objects into two list by size ratio and object keys partitioning

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataset, partitioning

I have an list of objects, let's call it `dataset` and I want to split into two new lists, let's call them `trainSet` and `testSet`, while reading the input `dataset` list line by line, where a list object inherits from a `node` read stream object (in this specific case).

Let's define then a split ratio `split_ratio=0.75` in order to split the `dataset` into a `trainSet` of at least 75% of the `dataset` and 25% of the `testSet` lists length (by example):

```
var dataSize = dataset.length,
    lim_75 = 0,
    lim_25 = 0;

lim_75 = Math.floor(dataSize * split_ratio); // e.g.: .75
if (lim_75 < 1) lim_75 = 1;
lim_25 = Math.floor(dataSize * (1 - split_ratio)); // eg: 1-.75=.25
if (lim_25 < 1) lim_25 = 1;
```

When reading line by line I will do

```
while (row = dataset.next()) {
    var r = Math.random(); // split randomness seed
    if (r < split_ratio && lim_75_count < lim_75 || r >= split_ratio && lim_25_count > lim_25) {
        lim_75_count += 1;
        trainSet.write(row);
    } else {
        lim_25_count += 1;
        testSet.write(row);
    }
}
```

This works, I will get at the end two lists `trainSet` of a size of 0.75 and `testSet` of 0.25 of the `dataset` list length.

Now, supposed that my objects in the `dataset` list, have a structure like

```
{
 objectId: 12345,
 objectClass: 'CLASS_A`
 objectValue: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
}
```

where `objectClass` belongs to an enumeration of values like `CLASS_A`, `CLASS_B`, etc.

I want to keep the `split_ratio`defined above for the `trainSet` and `testSet` length ratio, but adding a new condition that let me split the `dataset` with a new ratio, in order to partition the list by the object key `objectClass`, according to this partition map:

```
[
{
 objectClass: 'TYPE_A',
 ratio: 0.30
},
{
 objectClass: 'TYPE_B',
 ratio: 0.20
},
{
 objectClass: 'TYPE_C',
 ratio: 0.50
}
]
```

Which is the right partitioning condition that would work in `AND` with the first one based on size?

**EXAMPLE**

A real world example to clarify: 
Supposed that `split_ratio=.70`, you must have `trainSet.length=70`, `testSet.length=30` if `dataset.length=100.

Now, given two `objectClass` types with `ratio` values of

`CLASS_A=0.20` and `CLASS_B=0.80`, we must have `0.2*70/100` items of `CLASS_A` in the `trainSet` and `0.80*30/100` in the `testSet`, while we will have `0.80*70/100` items of `CLASS_B` in the `trainSet` and `0.20*30/100` items of `CLASS_B` in the `testSet`.

In this case supposes to have only `CLASS_A` and `CLASS_B` types in the partition map like:

```
[
{
     objectClass: 'TYPE_A',
     ratio: 0.20
    },
    {
     objectClass: 'TYPE_B',
     ratio: 0.80
    }
]
```

Comment: Is requirement for `objectClass` ratios  to be set at each `split_ratio` lists?

Comment: the `objectClass` should respect the `ratio` value in the partition map showed, so that for each `objectClass` enumeration type, the split will have that ratio in the resulting `trainSet` and `testSet` files.

Comment: Is the new partition map applied following `split_ratio`?

Comment: yes, the new partition map must apply the condition on `split_ratio` AND the conditions on the `objectClass` items `ratio`.

Comment: What should occur to remaining percentage of `"TYPE_A"`, `"TYPE_B"`, `"TYPE_C"`?